# What setting causes ENUM to be un-available in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: enums, settings, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to do a simple thing: add a column with datatype `ENUM` in a MySQL Workbench model. The problem is, the choice is just not there. I cannot select 'ENUM'.

If I open an old project or create a new one in the same Workbench I *do* have the choice, so it seems to be a setting, but I don't have a clue where to look. It's not some SQL thing, because an export and import (reverse engineer) in a new model also shows the `ENUM` columns.

*To be clear: it is NOT that I'm typing something like `enum(choice,choice2)` and so generating a syntax error, the dropdown has no `ENUM`.*

Tested on:

- Mysql Workbench version: 5.2.47 CE (revision 10398) on Windows 7
- Mysql Workbench version: 5.2.40 (revision 8790) on Ubuntu 13.04
- Mysql Workbench version: 6.0 community (build 6.0.3.11035) (BETA) on Windows 7

Settings for all projects are the same ('default'), in my case

- Default target mysql version: 5.5
- Storage engine: InnoDB
- SQL_MODE to be used: `TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES`

There seem to be several missing types, at least:

- BIT
- ENUM()
- SET()

Comment: You say you do not see ENUM in the column type drop down, but you *do* see it in another model. So if you load one you see ENUM and when you load the other you don't? That sounds very weird. I tried several models here, including creating a new one, and ENUM is always available. Please try MySQL Workbench 6.0 BETA and see if that solves your problem. If not then something with that specific model is wrong and we need a bug report to investigate (including a copy of the model).

Comment: The same happens on 6.0 BETA: it is always there, except for my little freak-model. The fact that the choices change per-model kinda feels like a setting (maybe something similar to the 'user types list'), but I can't find any. I'll update the latest findings in the question in a bit.

Comment: it does really sound like a bug, so I've opened a bug-report: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69763 .. if any updates I'll add them here, if any conclusions come up, i'll add an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I consider this now an official "bug" and therefore a real solution will not be forthcoming. 
Only thing you can do is start a new model, and re-create all your work there.